# Issue where the UINaviationsItem titleView's frame is set incorrectly when the titleView is set mid push animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationitem

I have a method to create a titleView.

```
- (void) makeTitleView {
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
}
```

This works fine when called in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self makeTitleView];
}
```

[image: Correct title view]

However if invoked after a small delay (less than the `pushViewController:animated:` animation time):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self makeTitleView];
    });
}
```

Then the title view is given the wrong frame:

[image: Incorrect title view]

At the end of the animation the frame sorts itself out.

This may seem contrived to set the title after 0.1 seconds but this situation is occurring on one of my apps.  The titleView needs to be set after a network request which which is returning after the next run loop when the results come from a cache.

I can avoid this issue but simply delaying by a longer time period or calling the method in `viewDidAppear:`, but both solutions introduce unnecessary delays.  Is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a placeholder title view and have its population be done after the network request is complete.

Your current setup seems a little fragile - usually any time you need to do dispatch_after it's either working round some UIKit bug or you need to restructure your approach.